# Why was I awarded the Matryoshka hat when I don't even have close-vote privileges?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

As you can see in the screenshot below, I have just been awarded the Matryoshka hat:

[image: Matryoshka]

I can't even vote to close or open any questions apart from my own, and I've only voted to reopen a single question. It seems this is a bug. How could I have legitimately earned this hat?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It turns out that certain types of flags (the "recommend closure" flags) are counted as close votes for the purposes of awarding the Matryoshka hat.

When community consensus is reached on the questions where I have raised recommend closure flags, and the questions get closed, that is counted as me being successfully involved in the closure of that question. Therefore, I have rightly earned the Matryoshka hat after all!

Comment: What kinds of flags are the "recommend closure" flags?

Comment: @kylejrp When you flag a question as "needs improvement". Each of the reasons on that dialog (duplicate, a community-specific reason, needs details or clarity, needs more focus, or opinion-based) will raise a "recommend closure" flag for the corresponding reason.